# Execute key RHS expression in Vim imperatively

Tags: vim, lua, neovim, keymapping

Given a string of inputs, it is possible to execute it using `:normal!`: `:normal! ihello` will go into insert mode and write the text 'hello'.

When mapping keys to expressions we can use a similar, albeit incompatible syntax. In Lua, we could, for example, define

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', 's', '<c-a>y')
```

Given such a string, `'<c-a>y'`, how would we execute it imperatively from within Lua/Vimscript without a key binding, similar to what is possible with `:normal!`?

Comment: The whole purpose of "cmd" is NEVER to execute the RHS as "normal". Otherwise, prefer "colon" notation.

Comment: @Matt the `<cmd>` was just an example. There is much more of this notation, like `<c-a>` that does not have such a replacement

Comment: Yes, I said (in my answer) that you have to make sure no other key notation left (`<c-a>` as (3c, 63, 2d, 61, 3e)). That is, either read already preprocessed data back from the mapping set, or process string yourself using api call.

Comment: @Matt ok thanks! Could you point me to the relevant API call that does this processing?

Comment: See in the help. Type `:help nvim_` and press tab to browse through completions. Something like `nvim_replace_termcodes`.

Comment: Actually, this is much simpler to do just `:normal s` (without exclamation sign). I still don't understand why do you want to do something with the RHS directly.

Answer (score 1):

"cmd" notation is not a replacement but alternative. Usually, the RHS of a mapping is processed as if (well, almost) typed. However, any "cmd"-thing is being processed much like as a script.

Therefore, you are supposed to strip "cmd" and "cr" off and pass it onto `execute`, not `normal`. Of course, after make sure that there is no other `<key>` notation left.